# Uploading and storing Docker certificates for connecting to remote Docker machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, docker, docker-api

From reading the Docker Remote API documentation:

[Docker Daemon over SSL](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/)
[Ruby Docker-API](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api)

It appears the the correct way to connect to remote Docker machines is by letting the application know the location of the certificates to connect to a machine and connect using SSL/TLS with the certificates.

Is there a way to not have a user hand over the certificate, key, and CA? This would give whomever has those certificates `root` access to a docker machine.

Comment: You want privileged access to a remote docker machine. How do you intend to do this without giving privileged access to the remote docker machine?

Comment: It seems weird that I need to upload the private key and public key...  With ssh you almost never expose your id_rsa private key

Comment: Which part of the documentation are you referring to? For https, the key is used by the daemon to sign the outbound, which is verified against the (public-key) cert. Which is in turn checked against the CA cert. The private key stays on the server that generated it though.

Comment: I'm looking at the SSL section and the Docker.options that appears to include the certificate,  private key,  and CA